# Definir o período de execução de uma aplicação

Tags: python, windows

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em Python que realiza cadastros no banco de dados acessando um e-mail e lendo cada um dos registros, gerando um insert por registro.

Preciso que essa aplicação fique executando no servidor diariamente, das 7:00 às 15:00, como faço para programar o servidor para executar essa aplicação nesse período especifico?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Já ouviu falar de tarefas agendadas do Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seja bem-vindo!

Você pode usar a biblioteca de agendamento de tarefas para o python chamada `schedule` (documentação [aqui](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/)). Com ela você pode agendar as tarefas a serem executadas, bem como organizar a duração e sequência. Você pode agendar tarefas tanto por horários específicos, quanto dias da semana, mês, ano, etc. Também pode setar intervalos diferentes e usar outros gatilhos para disparar a tarefa.

A vantagem de usar a biblioteca do `python` em vez de soluções como `Cron` e o agendador de tarefa do Windows, por exemplo, é não precisar reescrever o script. Também há casos em que o SO não suporta o recurso. Há também a vantagem de, como eu já disse, agendar tarefas que não sejam SOMENTE o tempo de execução. Você também fica mais à vontade nas questões de timezones e interações com recursos da linguagem.

Enfim, é isto.
(Obrigado quem comentou na postagem e pediu que eu melhorasse a resposta).

Boa sorte e bons estudos!

Comment: Porém, nesse caso, você precisará que o script fique 24h executando para gerenciar as tarefas. Será que é viável manter o script rodando das 15:00 às 07:00 de forma desnecessária?

Comment: O Anderson tem razão, para melhor eficiência seria melhor que um serviço do sistema operacional controle a execução do script, como o Agendador de Tarefas ou o Cron

Comment: Bem, não é assim que se propõe a ser o schedule do python. Como ele vai fazer isso por trás realmente não interessa. Mesmo com o agendador, alguma rotina precisa verificar se o script deve ou não ser disparado. Entre usar um recurso da linguagem e algo do sistema operacional, eu fico com o recurso da linguagem.

Comment: Vale dizer que as soluções do sistema operacional só servem para aquela plataforma. Qualquer migração o script deverá ser reescrito ou mesmo SO que não tem o recurso. Além disso, a maneira de disparar o script é via tempo nas soluções com via SO, mas usando o schedule você tem outras maneiras de fazer isso (intervalos diferentes, dias da semana, outras condições).

Comment: @IgorCavalcanti Talvez seria interessante expor tudo isso na resposta para fundamenta-la melhor.

Comment: Pronto, já o fiz. Percebi que meus comentários estão mal escritos devido à velocidade que fiz, sem pensar muito, só falando o que já sabia. Obrigado, Anderson e Fernando!